# How to find joint distribution of two normally distributed random variables?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, covariance, correlation

I have a problem with this exercise.

> Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent random variables with $Y_1∼N(1,3)$ and $Y_2∼N(2,5)$.
> If $W_1=Y_1+2Y_2$ and $W_2=4Y_1−Y_2$, what is the joint distribution of $W_1$ and $W_2$?

So I know that $W_1∼N(5,23)$ and $W_2∼N(2,53)$. But I also need the correlation coefficient for $W_1$ and $W_2$ for the variance-covariance matrix, how do I calculate this?

Do I need to calculate the covariance first, and in that case, how do I do that?

Comment: Hint: $\text{Cov}(aX + bY, cW + dZ) = ac\text{Cov}(X, W) + ad\text{Cov}(X, Z) + bc\text{Cov}(Y, W) + bd\text{Cov}(Y, Z)$. Use this to find the covariance between $W_1$ and $W_2$. Then the rest of the covariance-variance matrix should just be variances, which you know!

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

First note that $(Y_1,Y_2)'$ is bivariate normal because $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent.

Next observe that $$\left(\begin{array}{c}
W_{1}\\
W_{2}
\end{array}\right)=A\left(\begin{array}{c}
Y_{1}\\
Y_{2}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\
4 & -1
\end{array}\right),$$

and use the fact that affine transforms of normal random vectors are normal, i.e. $$X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)\implies AX+b\sim N(A\mu+b,A\Sigma A').$$

Comment: I know that $var(W_1)=23$ and $var(W_2)=53$ should be on the diagonal of the covariance matrix. But the problem is that I don´t know how to find $cov(W_1,W_2)$ to complete the matrix.

Comment: As suggested above, the covariance matrix of $(W_1,W_2)'$ will be $A\Sigma A'$ where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $(Y_1,Y_2)'$

Comment: I used that Cov(aX+bY,cW+dZ)=acCov(X,W)+adCov(X,Z)+bcCov(Y,W)+bdCov(Y,Z) that was commented above so I know how to do the rest now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @linmath No prob. My answer justifies the joint normality of $W_1,W_2$ as well.